# Canvas performance very slow in Chrome 49

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I've been working on an HTML5 game for close to a year now, and the newest version of Chrome (49) has completely wrecked its performance. The game that was easily running at 60FPS now struggles to get over 5-10 after updating Chrome. I've verified that it is the Chrome update using a stable version of the game and updating Chrome on my gaming PC, to see the same drop in performance.

I figured there would be something on the web or from Google about this by now, has anyone else seen this hit in performance? Is anyone aware of what has changed in Chrome that may have caused this issue?

Comment: Yes, looks like [there's at least 1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582781&q=label%3Aos-mac&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) rendering based performance bug been logged against 49.

Comment: [And another](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=569668).

Comment: Ugh. What were the queries you used in the bug tracker to dig those up? I appreciate the help here.

Comment: Just used google, limiting it to that site: `chrome 49 performance site:bugs.chromium.org`

Answer (score 0):

I did notice performance issues when calling drawImage() (about 10k sprites). The issue seems to be fixed in chrome 53, so I think it was a performance regression.

Comment: I take that back - Chrome 53 is just as crappy. Firefox however does a splendid job rendering the same thing, so it's a browser thing :( ...